# validating input in method

Tags: java, methods

i am new to java and currently trying to learn it!

I have a question about methods, here are my code example bellow.

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        char key;
        Scanner info = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Keyword: ");
        key = info.next().charAt(0);
        while(key!='W'&&key!='w'&&key!='M'&&key!='m')
        {   
            System.out.println("Invalid Keyword");
            System.out.print("Enter Keyword");
            key = info.next().charAt(0);
        }

        System.out.print("Valid key");
    }

    public static char validKey(char key)
    {
        ///i want the while validation to go here instead of in the main
    }
}
```

1. As i wrote in the code, is there a way to validate the key in the validKey method instead of in the main?
2. Is there a way so i dont have to specify between 'w' and 'W' in the while condition?

Sorry if i couldnt explain it well, thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) Return type of `validKey()`  should be `boolean`. (2) `Charctet`  has `toLowerCase()` method. See example: https://javatutorialhq.com/java/lang/character-class-tutorial/tolowercase-char-method-example/

Comment: (1) is there another way than using boolean? while i did try using it and it worked, i still wonder  if theres a way using char?
(2) thanks, the explanation was much of help!

Comment: Do you want to have a method that interfaces with a user and then return a valid key?
Something like `getValidKey()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to check is `key` correctly, you can do something like this:

```java
import java.util.*;

    public class test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            char key;
            Scanner info = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter Keyword: ");
            key = info.next().charAt(0);

            while(!validKey(key))
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Keyword");
                System.out.print("Enter Keyword");
                key = info.next().charAt(0);
            }

            System.out.print("Valid key");
        }

        public static boolean validKey(char key)
        {
            if(Character.toLowerCase(key)!='w' && Character.toLowerCase(key)!='m') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

2. It depends. If case size is not important you can try this:

```java
    while(Character.toLowerCase(key)!='w' && Character.toLowerCase(key)!='m')
    {   
        ...
    }
```

Write back if my answer will be helpfully for you ;)

Comment: for (1) thank you! i do find my own way but felt like it was over complicated and not too efective
(2) i just put 'key = Character.toLowerCase(key);' bellow the input read so i dont have  to do it everytime i use key

Comment: In this case ```key = Character.toLowerCase(key);``` is better option but using it you are modifying input variable. In more complicated programs it's not a good way I think :)